# How do I auto trust repos via a batch file for Visual Studio?

Tags: batch-file, automation, visual-studio-2022

I have a batch file already, that clones all of the repos I need.

When I load Visual Studio and try to access any of them, I have to select "Trust Repository" for each one, because I haven't cloned them via Visual Studio; they work fine when you do clone via Visual Studio.

Is there a way I can add a command when I clone the repo, to add this trust flag before I load Visual Studio?

[image]

Comment: You  *might* be able to add the folder you are cloning these repositories into via the Trust Settings and see if that fixes it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/trust-settings?view=vs-2022 I'll post an answer if it does.  I'm not sure if this setting will also work for this repositories window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

I have tried adding my local repo folder as a trusted location, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the issue for existing folders, as I still need to manually trust them.